Theme dependent CSS formatting in ZK
I have a ZK application with some CSS formatting. The colors in my CSS were chosen according to the Sapphire theme (unfortunately I have to use ZK 7). Now I want to have environment dependent themes (Sapphire for production, Breeze for stage). It works fine but I would like to change some of my custom CSS rules (mostly background-color) according to the selected theme.
Is there an easy way for it, for example

theme dependent CSS files, or
theme dependent CSS selectors, or
using some color constants from ZK themes in my CSS rule, or something else?


If you have a way to tell (in Java) where your project is executed, then it's as easy as calling Library.setProperty("org.zkoss.theme.preferred", "custom"); (where you replace custom by a string containing the name of the theme you want to load) in a WebAppInit listener. Alternatively, you can implement your own ThemeResolver to have full control over which theme gets selected.
Depending on your what your web server is, you could check for a VM argument (and set it in your tomcat senEnv file, or as part of your run command on a spring-boot project, etc.). Any environment-specific value will do, as longs as you can test for it in Java.
Edit:
Regarding using specific files / rules per theme:
ZK puts the theme name on the body element of the page.
so any rule like .themeName yourSelector{} will apply only to that theme.
.breeze .z-textbox{
 // apply to breeze theme only
}


Also, this would be a good use case for CSS variables (custom properties) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties . If you structure your custom CSS to declare these custom variables based on the theme class located on the body element, you can override the default with new variable value. Then in your main style, you refer to the variables instead of putting the value directly.
